# Array.splice works, Lodash.remove doesn't

Tags: javascript, mongoose, lodash

I'm deleting an item from an array with `mongoose`. Some code:

```
const { find, remove } = require('lodash');

....

UserSchema.methods.deleteItem = async function (id) {
  const user = this;
  const item = find(user.items, i => i.id === id);
  const idx = user.items.indexOf(item);
  user.items.splice(idx, 1);

  // remove(user.items, i => i.id === id);

  try {
    await user.save();
    return item;
  } catch (err) {
    throw new Error(err);
  }
};
```

In the above code, I use `splice()`, which works correctly. However, lodash's `remove` doesn't work. The [documentation](https://lodash.com/docs/4.17.10#remove) for `.remove()` says that it mutates the array directly, so why does it not work here?

Comment: you show it as `remove()` not `_.remove()`. Is that a typo...or the answer?

Comment: @charlietfl I also see `find`, so I am guessing the OP might have used `const {find, remove} = _;`.

Comment: @zero298 ahh..probably right. Never hurts to ask though

Comment: @zero298 Yep, that's right, good catch. Added to the question now! :)

Comment: I have not worked with mongoose before, but there is no reason for lodash's remove to behave as you describe. So, I have questions:
1) Why don't you think it's working? IE where and how are you inspecting the value and not seeing the "expected" state?
2) What is user.items? Is it a plain-old-javascript-array or does mongoose do some special wrapping?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In short, Mongoose and Lodash do not appear to be compatible (at least for this use case).

---

Mongoose wraps `Array.splice` with its own method.

Please see line 568 of [Mongoose source](https://github.com/Automattic/mongoose/blob/0ef7f26ebbb07b4bde78831c1b333792dc76fd08/lib/types/array.js)

However, Lodash explicitly calls the default `Array.splice`, which circumvents the wrapped version.

Please see (in order) lines 7847, 7864, 3857, 3866, 1484, 1435 of [Lodash source](https://github.com/lodash/lodash/blob/4.17.10/lodash.js#L7847)

Answer (score -3):

According to the docs `remove` "Returns the new array of removed elements". So in order to achieve what you want you need to assign the return value of the invokation to user.items.

https://lodash.com/docs/4.17.10#remove

Comment: *"Unlike _.filter, this method mutates array"*